# How to automate blender video sequencer

Tags: scripting, video-sequence-editor

Is it possible to automate the sequencer so that each time I render an animation into image files in a folder, the newly rendered image files would be inputted into the sequencer in a specific arrangement or something like this?:

1. Load images 1-300 and place in sequencer
2. Load images 1-300, again, and place after first image sequence
3. Apply backwards effect to the second image sequence

If not an option in blender, is there a way to create a script to do this? Often I will rerender the same animation with a different setting or something, but every time I have to manually apply what was described above. I'm not necessarily asking for a solution specified to this example, but for all examples like this. Is there something that would work to automate this process?

Any help is appreciated. If what I am describing is unclear I can further describe it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, blenders sequencer has full Python API access so it can be used to do quite advanced video editing both from the UI or in background mode (headless).

```
import os

from bpy import context
scene = context.scene

path = "/my_path/to/images"
files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()

# create the sequencer data
scene.sequence_editor_create()

seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image(
        name="MyStrip",
        filepath=os.path.join(path, files[0]),
        channel=1, frame_start=1)

# add the rest of the images.
for f in files:
    seq.elements.append(f)

# reverse if you want
seq.use_reverse_frames = False
```

# You may want to render the result:

```
render = scene.render
scene.frame_start = 1
scene.frame_end = 1 + len(files)

render.resolution_x = 1280
render.resolution_y = 720
render.fps = 25

render.image_settings.file_format = 'FFMPEG'
render.ffmpeg.format = 'MPEG4'
render.ffmpeg.codec = 'H264'

render.ffmpeg.constant_rate_factor = 'HIGH'
render.ffmpeg.ffmpeg_preset = 'BEST'

bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
```

The rest I'm sure you can work out as you may want to tweak encoding, frame rate... etc.

Comment: You've kinda left out the most important part: How to sequence that strip into a video.

Comment: This could be fairly large depending on what codecs, format etc you want to set. Added brief block for rendering results.

Comment: Thanks a million. You saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, It is quite possible (ideasman42 already gave an example of the Sequencer API usage).

You can also setup the automation logic that will create/update your sequencer using a [render complete handler](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70_release/bpy.app.handlers.html?highlight=handlers#bpy.app.handlers.render_complete). In your addon, You can register the sequencer setup handler to run after render completes.

```
@bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def process_in_sequencer(self, context):
    <logic goes here>

bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(process_in_sequencer)
```