# Python script for adding images always puts in the first file in the folder. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, import

I have some code (with elements from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8107/how-to-automate-blender-video-sequencer)) that should work but gives me a weird error.
I import images in strips inside a while loop. The images imported are defined via the frame_range_ parameters. The frame_range_forw_start and the frame_range_back_start work, as the sequence is progressing but they also import the first file in the folder, which is not intended.

```
 import os

from bpy import context
scene = context.scene

path = "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Projects/VIDEO/atabilized/timelapse"

files = os.listdir(path)
files.sort()

amp = 20 #Min 1  
end = 250 
i = 0


    # create the sequencer data

while i <= end - amp + 1:

    starta = amp * i * 2 # start of forward motion
    startb = (amp * i * 2) + amp # start of backward motion

    frame_range_forw_start = (1 + i * 2) # first imported image of forward motion
    frame_range_forw_end = (1 + i * 2 + amp) # last imported image of forward motion
    frame_range_back_start = (2 + i * 2) # first imported image of backward motion (strip will be reversed)
    frame_range_back_end = (2 + i * 2 + amp) # last imported image of backward motion (strip will be reversed)

    scene.sequence_editor_create()

    seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image(
                name="MyStrip",
                filepath=os.path.join(path, files[0]),
                channel=1, frame_start=starta)

    # add the rest of the images.
    for f in files[frame_range_forw_start:frame_range_forw_end]:
            seq.elements.append(f)

    seq = scene.sequence_editor.sequences.new_image(
                name="MyStrip",
                filepath=os.path.join(path, files[0]),
                channel=2, frame_start=startb)

    # add the rest of the images.
    for f in files[frame_range_back_start:frame_range_back_end]:
            seq.elements.append(f)

    # reverse if you want
    seq.use_reverse_frames = True
    #bpy.ops.sequencer.gap_remove(all=False)    
    i += 1
```

The first imported image in every strip (from frame_range_forw_start AND frame_range_back_start) is ALWAYS the first file in the folder. The frames after are correct.

[image: this is the right frame]
this is the right frame
[image: this is the first image in the folder]
this is the first image in the folder

What have I done wrong?

I also tried it with other equations:

```
frame_range_forw_start = (i)
frame_range_forw_end = (i + amp)
frame_range_back_start = (2 + i)
frame_range_back_end = (2 + i + amp)
```

But the problem persists.

Comment: On a quick glance would move `scene.sequence_editor_create()` outside the while loop, it only needs to be called once (if `scene.sequence_editor is None`)

Comment: Thank you. I have done it. Didn't fix the issue though.

Comment: Is `filepath=os.path.join(path, files[0]),` the first file in folder?

Comment: Thank you so much. I replaced
filepath=os.path.join(path, files[0])
with
filepath=os.path.join(path, files[i]) and
filepath=os.path.join(path, files[2+i])
And now it works. :)

Comment: Excellent. Write up explanation as answer. (backticks (above tab) marks up code in comments)